# Firebug extension to "Re-send" ajax post/get things

Tags: ajax, firefox, firebug

In Firebug we can see the "network" tab. 
So there we see all the connections made by any page.

I was thinking is there any Extension that add the option "resend" to them..

Example:

POST /file.php name=john  Answer: Anything..

We could right click on it, and ask for "resend" than it connect again with this file and post the same thing again..

Is there already a way to do that?

Comment: Ah, I finally understand this.. lol..

Answer (score 2):

From [What’s New in Firebug 1.9](http://www.sitepoint.com/firebug-19-new-features/)

> Resend HTTP Requests
>
> ```
>  This is a great new feature: right-click any request shown in the Console or Net panels and hit Resend to execute the request again.
> ```

Comment: Im missing a keyboard shortcut for this instead of clicking on Resend, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is exactly the option you are asking for if you right click on a post request in the 'net' section of Firebug's console.